# Is it possible to target Windows and Android from the same Visual Studio project in VS2015 & VS2017?

Tags: android, windows, visual-studio-2015, static-libraries, visual-studio-2017

Background: I have a project which targets Windows and Android, and depends on a number of static library projects (.lib / .a).

I am reasonably familiar with Visual Studio project-file syntax & don't mind hand-editing project files in a text/XML editor.

What I'd like to do is have the static libraries for the two platforms build from the same project files, but inherit from different property sheets (or conditional groups within the same property sheet).

I can do, for example:

```
>  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Platform)'=='Win32'">
>    <Import Project="windows_settings.props" />
>  </ImportGroup>
>  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Platform)'=='ARM64'">
>    <Import Project="android_settings.props" />
>  </ImportGroup>
```

But I don't seem to be able to target both Windows and Android from the same *.vcxproj - if I use platform-conditionals around e.g. the  area, it doesn't switch from one system to another when I change the platform target from the drop-down.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem today. The OpenGLES 2 Application template found in Visual Studio 2015 handles deploying to multiple platforms by placing shared code into a "Shared Items Project", then creating separate projects for each platform which references this Shared code.